# SwiftUI I'd like to get a text from the console

Tags: swift, swiftui, contacts

```swift
VStack {

.onAppear {
                
                for cont in contactsVM.contacts {
                    
                    info = "\(cont.firstName) \(cont.lastName);\(cont.phone);//"
                    
                }
                
            }
}
```

If you save the text in the info and print it out, only one text comes out

[image]

I want to get all the text that appears on the console

I'm going to take it and use it as a text editor

---

There's an error

[image]

this is My ViewModel

```swift
getContacts() {
        
        Contact.fetchAll { [weak self] result in
            guard let self = self else { return }
                switch result {
                case .success(let fetchedContacts):
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.contacts = fetchedContacts.sorted(by: {$0.lastName < $1.lastName})
                    }
                case.failure(let error):
                    self.permissionsError = .fetchError(error)
                }
            
        }
    }
```

And model
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You overwrite `info` in each iteration of the loop so eventually it contains the data of the last item of the array.

Rather than with a loop you could `map` the data and convert the array to string (paragraphs) with `joined(separator:)`

```
VStack {
    .onAppear {
        info = contactsVM.contacts.map{"\($0.firstName) \($0.lastName);\($0.phone);//"}.joined(separator: "\n")         
    }
}
```

Comment: I made a mistake The problem has been solved Thank you so much!!!!

Answer (score 0):

When you are running the for loop , with every iteration the value of info is changing to a new value. This is the reason you are seeing only one value.

use this instead.

```
        var info = ""
        for contact in contactsVM.contacts {
            info.append("\(cont.firstName) \(cont.lastName);\(cont.phone) \n")
        }
```